# adding a div on another div targeting specific location, based on values, using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to color an area of a img, based on selection values.

example:

HTML markup:

```
       <tr id="from"> <!-- Hide this table unless yes selected -->
        <td>
            from
        </td>
        <td>
           <select name="from" id="from" style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">

                <option value="" name="" selected="selected">....</option>

                <?php

                $i = 0;
                while ($i <= 23) {
                    if ($i<10) {
                        echo '<option value="f' . $i . '" name="f' . $i . '">0' . $i . '.00</option>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<option value="f' . $i . '" name="f' . $i . '">' . $i . '.00</option>';
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>


            </select>
        </td>
       </tr>

       <tr id="to"> <!-- Hide this table unless yes selected -->
        <td>
            to
        </td>
        <td>
           <select name="to" id="to" style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">

                <option value="" name="" selected="selected">....</option>

                <?php

                $i = 0;
                while ($i <= 23) {
                    if ($i<10) {
                        echo '<option value="t' . $i . '" name="t' . $i . '">0' . $i . '.00</option>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<option value="t' . $i . '" name="t' . $i . '">' . $i . '.00</option>';
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>


            </select>
        </td>
       </tr>


      <tr id="timer_table"> <!-- Hide this table unless yes selected -->
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="img/time_line.png" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: 1px solid #d1d2d4;" />
        </td>
       </tr>
```

Basicly the user is supposed to pick a start time, and a end time, and that part is supposed to be colord on the time_line img.

"time_line.png" is 339x10 pixels, and the color pic is "cover_red.png" which is 14x10 pixels, its 0.125 pixels off, but thats okay.

So what i want to do, is put the color img, on to the timeline img, to color it based on selection, using javascript.

I have no idea how to do this, if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very helpful.

Comment: You may not need "cover_red.png" if it only contains just a solid red background (if it's a pattern then ignore this comment), you could just use a `<div>` with a red background and set its `z-index` so that it's on top of the time line image, and set its position/width accordingly (jQuery's `css()` function is very handy for this).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to solving this may be an image-map. The `<img>` tag `usemap` attribute (see plentiful HTML documentation) allows clickable regions of images. Using the `z-index` CSS attribute could also be used to layer over different elements with different background colors (or image sprites) based on variable input. Place these layers appropriately using CSS `position:absolute` top/right over the background base image at the lowest `z-index`.